# Rudin mathematical analysis chapter 4 problem 21

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

Rudin's mathematical analysis chapter 4 exercise 21:

> Suppose $K$ and $F$ are disjoint sets in a metric space $X$, $K$ is
>   compact, $F$ is closed. Prove that there exists $\delta>0$ such that
>   $d(p,q)>\delta$ if $p \in K$, $q \in F$. Hint: $\rho_{F}$ is a
>   continuous positive function on $K$.
>
> Show that the conclusion may fail for two disjoint closed sets if
>   neither is compact.

**Proof 1**:
Define $\rho_{F}(x)=\inf_{z \in F}d(x,z)\geq0$. According to exercise 20, $\rho_{F}(x)=0$ if and only if $x\in F=\bar{F}$. Because $F$ is closed and $K\bigcap F=\emptyset$, $K\bigcap \bar{F}=\emptyset$. Therefore, $\rho_{F}(x)>0$ if $p\in K$. We can surely find a $\delta>0$ such that $d(p,q)>\delta$ if $p\in K$, $q \in F$.

Where am I wrong in this proof please?

---

Comment: the last statement in Proof 1 is wrong, we cannot find a minimum distance among an infinite set.

**Proof 2**: Because $K$ and $F$ are disjoint and $F$ is closed, for every point $p \in K$, we can find a neighbourhood such that $N_{\epsilon}(p) \bigcap F=\emptyset$. Because $K$ is compact, we can find finite such neighbourhoods $N_{\epsilon_1}(p1), N_{\epsilon_2}(p2), N_{\epsilon_3}(p3), \cdots, N_{\epsilon_N}(p_N)$ such that they form an open over of $K$. Obviously, for any $p \in K$, $q \in F$, we have $d(p, q)>min(\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2, \cdots, \epsilon_N)>0$.

But why

> $\rho_{F}$ is a continuous positive function on $K$.

is necessary then?

Comment: The question seems misstated. After "prove that there exists $\delta > 0$", $\delta$ is never mentioned again.

Comment: @Bungo Thank you for your kind reminder. Correction done.

Comment: The question doesn't define $\rho_F$. You define it in the first line of the proof. I assume that there's a missing $d$ and it should be $\inf_{z \in F}d(x,z)$?

Comment: @Bungo You are right, thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infimum of a set of positive numbers may be $0$. The facts that $\rho_F(p)$ is a continuous function of $p$ on $K$ and $K$ is compact implies that the infimum is positive because infimum is attained at some point of $K$. This argument fails if $K$ just a closed set. Example:  $\{2,3,...\}$ and $\{2+\frac 1 2,3+\frac 1 3,...\}$ are disjoint closed sets at distance $0$.

Comment: Is $2$ not in both $\{1,2,3,\dots\}$ and $\{1+1,2+1/2,\dots\}$?

Comment: @user254433 Thanks for the comment. $2$ was the only point in both the sets so all you have to do is omit the  first elements of the two sets.

Answer (score 2):

If there does not exist a $\delta$ then there exists $p_n,q_n$ with $p_n \in K, q_n \in K$ such that $d(p_n,q_n) \leq \frac{1}{n}$. Since $K$ is compact there is a convergent subsequence of $q_n$ say  $\{q_{n_m}\}$. Hence $\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} q_{n_m} = \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} p_{n_m}=x$, Since both $K,F$ are closed $x \in K, x \in F$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but why $K$ is closed?

Comment: In  a metric space, $K$ compact implies $K$ is also closed.

Comment: Thank you. In your proof, we don't need $\rho_F$  to be a continuous function?

Comment: I am not using it...

Answer (score 0):

*A counterexample*. Consider $K=\{(x,y):y>1/x,\ x\geq1\}$, $F=\{(x,y):y<-1/x,\ x\geq1\}$. They are closed but the distance between them is 0.

Comment: @SamuelDupuis I wanted to accept your correct edition but it had been already rejected by Community. :-( Good luck in next editions!